# How to delete Linefeed using batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I want to delete Linefeed in text file using batch file.
Is it possible to do.
Please provide some help

Comment: Do yourself a favor, don't try to do useful work in dos-batch, it will make you cry. Instead try `flip`: it's old, it works, no crying needed. https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~craig/utility/flip/

Comment: @msw: That pretty much only depends on the expertise of the person doing it and how widely the solution needs to be deployed. I frequently avoid non-standard dependencies if I can help it. sureshdharmadurai: You may want to elaborate a little because right now I don't see much use in your question. As I understand it you want to delete line breaks from the file, converting it into a single line. However, I suspect that's not what you'd want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean removing empty lines from text files try this in a batch file:

```
for /f "delims= tokens=*" %%x in (inputfile.txt) do echo %%x >> outputfile.txt
```

you may also want to replace **inputfile.txt** and **outputfile.txt** by **%1** and **%2** to be used for any file given its name to the batch file