# Removing "enter" character with batch?

Tags: batch-file, exiftool

I use a tool called "exiftool" for reading metadata information from video file for Listing/Categorization. Exiftool output is something like this.

```
1920x1080
2:58:09
12421 MB
```

What I want is;

```
[1920x1080][2:58:09][12421 MB]
```

This is what I am trying to do for removing "enter" character;

```
:_Dongu2
set GELEN=%~1
set /a SAYAC2+=1
if %SAYAC2% LEQ 99 (
  if %SAYAC2% LEQ 9 (
    title Ilerleme Durumu: 00%SAYAC2% / %FSAY%
  ) else (
    title Ilerleme Durumu: 0%SAYAC2% / %FSAY%
  )
) else (
  title Ilerleme Durumu: %SAYAC2% / %FSAY%
)

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "firstLineReady="
(
    for /F "eol=$ delims=" %%a in ('exiftool -s3 -ImageSize -Duration -FileSize "%~1\%GELEN:~20,-23%.mp4"') DO (
        if defined firstLineReady (echo()
        set "firstLineReady=1"
        <nul set /p "=%%a"
    )
)>> out.txt
goto :EOF
```

So far I didn't work it out. I found this function from [Jeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254067/batch-delete-line-feed-from-end-of-text-file/6262823#6262823) on another question. This is the way I call this function

```
(for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (%MTEMP%) do call :_Dongu2 "%%x") && title %NAME%
```

and `%MTEMP%` file is like

```
Z:\Movies\000y.001y\The.Lord.of.the.Rings.The.Fellowship.of.the.Ring.(2001){0120737}[00085]
Z:\Movies\000y.001y\The.Lord.of.the.Rings.The.Return.of.the.King.(2003){0167260}[00087]
Z:\Movies\000y.001y\The.Lord.of.the.Rings.The.Two.Towers.(2002){0167261}[00086]
```

each movies attitude had to be on another line. out.txt had to be like;

```
[1920x1080][2:58:09][12421 MB][The.Lord.of.the.Rings.The.Fellowship.of.the.Ring]
[1920x1080][3:02:31][14660 MB][The.Lord.of.the.Rings.The.Return.of.the.King]
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a batch solution:

```
@echo off
<"file.txt" (
set /p a=
set /p b=
set /p c=
) 
echo [%a%][%b%][%c%]
```

Output:

```
[1920x1080][2:58:09][12421 MB]
```

Comment: Works lke a charm...Thanks.

Comment: This was my first thought as soon as I reached the `What I want` bit!

Answer (score 1):

Directly ask exiftool to produce the required output

```
exiftool -p [${ImageSize}][${Duration}][${FileSize}] videoFile.mp4
```

Comment: Your way is a lot more better but what i was looking for the one foxidrive said.