# Batch: delete line feed from end of text file using filepaths

Tags: windows, batch-file

This question is related to this question:
[Batch: delete line feed from end of text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254067/batch-delete-line-feed-from-end-of-text-file)

So I have a txt-file containing some information and I want to remove the last rows LFCR (line feed, carriage return) chars.

I need to point out the source file path and the destination file path using variables and the filename as a parameter (%1).

**The batch code**

```
@echo off
set @srcfile="D:\AgrCC\AgrTest\Report Results\%1"
set @dstfile="D:\AgrCC\AgrTest\Data Export\%1"
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "firstLineReady="
(
    for /F "eol=$ delims=" %%a in (%@srcfile%) DO (
        if defined firstLineReady (echo()
        set "firstLineReady=1"
        <nul set /p "=%%a"
    )
) > %@dstfile%
```

But instead of removing the LFCR chars I end up with a file looking like this in the destination folder:

**Destination file content**

```
D:\AgrCC\AgrTest\Report Results\bg1baa.725
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the for-loop you need the `usebackq` option, so that you can still use a quoted filename to be safe against spaces.

Do not add the quotation marks to the variable content, instead use the extended `set syntax`.

```
set "var=content"`
```

You should change

```
set "@srcfile=D:\AgrCC\AgrTest\Report Results\%~1"
set "@dstfile=D:\AgrCC\AgrTest\Data Export\%~1"
...
for /F "usebackq eol=$ delims=" %%a in ("%@srcfile%") DO (
...
) > "%@dstfile%"
```